# List all records under month with month as tablerow

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I'm sure there's a way to do this but I'm suffering from sleep deprivation and could really use some help.

Here's what I need. I have a table with headers and rows of data listed underneath - it looks great but, I need to add a table row between the rows of data when the month changes to separate out the months.

Here's what I have:

```
Date         Time          Event           
08-31-2013   6:00 pm EST   Horseshoe Tourney
09-07-2013   8:00 pm EST   Movie Night
09-28-2013   5:00 pm EST   Dinner on the Quad
10-12-2013   4:30 pm EST   Sing-a-long
10-31-2013   7:00 pm EST   Halloween Party
11-14-2013   4:00 pm EST   Hay Ride
```

Here's what I need:

```
Date         Time          Event 
AUGUST (to span the whole table row)          
08-31-2013   6:00 pm EST   Horseshoe Tourney
SEPTEMBER (to span the whole table row)  
09-07-2013   8:00 pm EST   Movie Night
09-28-2013   5:00 pm EST   Dinner on the Quad
OCTOBER (to span the whole table row)  
10-12-2013   4:30 pm EST   Sing-a-long
10-31-2013   7:00 pm EST   Halloween Party
NOVEMBER (to span the whole table row)  
11-14-2013   4:00 pm EST   Hay Ride
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is code I'm using to create the table now.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white;">
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Date</th>
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Time</th>
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Event</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
  // Write rows
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($row['date']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Here's what ended up working for me! Sure do appreciate the help!

```
<?php
  // Write rows
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    $month='';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if(date("F", strtotime($row['date']))!==$month){
            $month=date("F", strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><?= $month ?></td></tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($row['date']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $month=date("F", strtotime($row['date']));
    } 
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete Bekisz - I was trying to figure out how to get those to line up. Obviously, it's my first time using Stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries! We've all been there :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white;">
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Date</th>
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Time</th>
        <th style="background-color:#8a0028; color:white; text-align:left;">Event</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
  // Write rows
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    $month='';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if(date("F", strtotime($row['date']))!==$month){
            $month=date("F", strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><?= $month ?></td></tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($row['date']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: thanks to both! It was a combo of both that ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

Essentially, at the beginning of each loop, you're testing to see if the month is different from the previous one. If it is, you output a new row.

```
<?php
        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        $last_month = '';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 ?>

<?php if (date("M", strtotime($row['month'])) != $last_month): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><?php echo date("M", strtotime($row['month'])); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($row['date']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event'];?></td>
        </tr>

<?php 
        $last_month = date("M", strtotime($row['month']));
    } 
?>
```

Comment: First - thank you so much for your help!! One more question. If I wanted to check the value of the $row['month'] so that it would check to see the numerical value of the month and write the actual month name - how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Instead of `<?php echo date("M", strtotime($row['month'])); ?>`, use `date("F", strtotime($row['month']))`. I'd suggest reviewing http://www.pep.net/date.